# Dynamic ROW count Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction regarding a problem I am trying to solve in Excel.

I would like to have a cell count the number of cells within a range that contain any data.  So.. COUNTA.

However, I would like this count to update dynamically when rows are inserted into the range (making the range larger).

Right now I can do this by using

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("C7:C" &ROW()-1))
```

If I insert a ROW after C7 and above the row where my formula is, the count will go up.

My problem is that I would like to use this formula for multiple separate ranges in the same column.

If I have

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("C7:C" &ROW()-1))
```

and

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("C12:C" &ROW()-1))
```

working in my sheet, the second formulas count becomes inaccurate when a row is inserted into the first "range".

Hopefully that makes sense.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("C"&ROW($C$7)&":C" &ROW()-1))
```

This will allow the referenced cell to change as rows are inserted.

See also: [Increase the Row referenced in INDIRECT when dragging a formula down](https://superuser.com/questions/1175800/increase-the-row-referenced-in-indirect-when-dragging-a-formula-down?rq=1)